Aborting/crashing programs don't generate core files on system created with Buildroot 24.02
I'm trying to get programs that abort/crash to generate core dump files under buildroot.
I'm testing by running a C program which just calls the abort() function.  I can't seem to get a core file to be generated.
Here is what I've tried/checked so far:

ulimit -c is unlimited
The kernel core pattern is set to /tmp/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t
This is verified by running sysctl kernel.core_pattern
/tmp isn't full and can be written by all
The file /etc/security/limits.conf exists, and has the following contents:


my_username soft core unlimited
my_username hard core unlimited
root soft core unlimited
root hard core unlimited


/proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid has the value 1
defaultcorelimit is not specified in /etc/systemd/system.conf

Thanks to Arnout, I found that BR2_PACKAGE_SYSTEMD_COREDUMP is not set.  Will try that and update the question.
Edit: Enabled BR2_PACKAGE_SYSTEMD_COREDUMP.  Still not getting core dumps.

What does journalctl -t systemd-coredump show? Maybe there is something weird going on with abort(). You should get a coredump by kill -SIGABRT <pid> for any PID on the running system.

@stu Running journalctl -t systemd-coredump reports no entries.

Is BR2_PACKAGE_SYSTEMD_COREDUMP enabled? (Please update your question with this information.)

@Arnout - I enabled BR2_PACKAGE_SYSTEMD_COREDUMP.  Still not getting core dumps.
